# Exchange push notifications without EWS access

Tags: exchange

I am working on a project which will use near real-time room appointment information from Microsoft Exchange. The customer Exchange server and EWS are private and will not be accessible by the client application.

Is it possible to configure streaming or push notifications with a client that does not have direct access to EWS? Based on what I've read, the client must first subscribe to streaming/push notifications before Exchange will send them.

- Can subscriptions be created programmatically on the server as long as the server can communicate with the client?
- If the Exchange server loses connection to the client, would the subscriptions  have to be re-created on the server?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve appointments and meetings from a calendar folder by using the CalendarFolder.FindAppointments EWS Managed API method.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-appointments-and-meetings-by-using-ews-in-exchange#get-appointments-by-using-the-ews-managed-api

After the timeout value elapses, the OnDisconnect event is raised. If the StreamingSubscriptionConnection.Open method is not called, the connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks, but as stated above, the client application will not have access to the EWS endpoint. I need the Exchange server to push data to the client without the client initiating the subscription.

Comment: You might get answer in the following forum, please have a try:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/home?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment